# Embedding WinForms Graph in WPF Window

Tags: wpf, winforms, graph, integration, charts

I've tried to embed a .NET WinForms graph (Stephan Zimmermann's Graph Display) in a WPF window, under a WindowsFormsHost (I've referenced both System.Windows.Forms and WindowsFormsIntegration).

However, I can see the form panel but not the graph. I've ran the demo application on a windows form and it worked, but when I transfered the same code to the WPF window, I saw that the data is updated but not shown on the graph.

Thank everyone in advance,

Yaron.

Comment: Could you post your WPF code?

Answer (score 19):

Could you try the following code and see if you can get a graph to display and then work from there?

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Dictionary<int, double> value;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            value = new Dictionary<int, double>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                value.Add(i, 10 * i);

            Chart chart = this.FindName("MyWinformChart") as Chart;
            chart.DataSource = value;
            chart.Series["series"].XValueMember = "Key";
            chart.Series["series"].YValueMembers = "Value";
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:winformchart="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="392" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>

        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="host" Height="300">
            <winformchart:Chart x:Name="MyWinformChart" Dock="Fill">
                <winformchart:Chart.Series>
                    <winformchart:Series Name="series" ChartType="Line"/>
                </winformchart:Chart.Series>
                <winformchart:Chart.ChartAreas>
                    <winformchart:ChartArea/>
                </winformchart:Chart.ChartAreas>
            </winformchart:Chart>
        </WindowsFormsHost>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

making sure you have references to:

%ProgramFiles%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\WindowsFormsIntegration.dll

%ProgramFiles%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll

%ProgramFiles%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Windows.Forms.dll

I have this running after shamelessly copying the following [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/wpf/thread/e7caf74f-29c8-42a4-87b5-13b520d0d587)

Comment: Can I do binding with chart series?

Answer (score 4):

Although the question is more than 6 years old I had a similar (if not the same issue), when trying to create and add the Chart object at runtime.
Thanks to Bobwah's suggestion I could isolate the problem and found that I simply had to add a ChartArea to the Chart object to see the graph:

```
Chart chart = new Chart();
chart.ChartAreas.Add("MainChartArea"); //this was missing
chart.Series.Add(getSeries());
chart.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
host.Child = chart; //'host' is the WPF-WindowsFormsHost control
```

Hope it helps someone... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in WPF. Luckily I got the solution.

I observed that chart areas and series are being reset once the data source is set. It looks like a bug for me.

So, the workaround/solution is to set the data source at very first place before adding the things like chart areas and series.

Answer (score 0):

Set the graph as the child of the WindowsFormsHost object.

Comment: Already done it, it didn't help. I still can't see the graph updates.