# NameScope issue with FindName() for Win Form Chart in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts

I am attempting to use a Windows Form Chart (`System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting`) in my WPF application. I am following [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377862/embedding-winforms-graph-in-wpf-window), and so far it's been quite helpful. I can create a new WPF Application, copy/paste the code word for word and it works as expected.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace MetroApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        Dictionary<int, double> value;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            InitializeComponent();

            value = new Dictionary<int, double>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                value.Add(i, 10 * i);

            Chart chart = this.FindName("MyWinformChart") as Chart;

            chart.DataSource = value;
            chart.Series["series"].XValueMember = "Key";
            chart.Series["series"].YValueMembers = "Value";
        }
    ...
    }
...
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MetroApplication3.MainWindow"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:winformchart="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization"
          Title="My App" Name="mainWindow" Height="695.522" Width="1019.403" Foreground="White" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Icon="favicon.ico">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Name="tabControl1">
            <TabItem Name="tab1" Header="Tab 1">
                ...
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Name="tab2" Header="Tab 2">
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Name="chartPanel">
                        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="host" Height="300">
                            <winformchart:Chart x:Name="MyWinformChart" Dock="Fill">
                                <winformchart:Chart.Series>
                                    <winformchart:Series Name="series" ChartType="Line"/>
                                </winformchart:Chart.Series>
                                <winformchart:Chart.ChartAreas>
                                    <winformchart:ChartArea/>
                                </winformchart:Chart.ChartAreas>
                            </winformchart:Chart>
                        </WindowsFormsHost>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The project Build's without issue, but when I Start the program, I get "`TargetInvocationException` was unhandled". An unhandled exception of type `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` occurred in `PresentationFramework.dll`.

After researching this issue, I'm pretty sure I've determined the issue lies with the NameScope of the Window. I think this is because I have the `Chart` nested inside a `TabItem`. I've tested the result of `Chart chart = this.FindName("MyWinformChart") as Chart;` in MainWindow.xaml.cs and `chart` is null.

What steps do I need to take to solve this namescoping issue? Can I not use `this.FindName("MyWinformChart")` if the control is nested how I have it? How would I modify the statement?