# how to add .net chart component in wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to use a .NET framework component in WPF - Systems.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting Chart Component - and even though I have this selected in the "Choose Toolbox Items" dialog in VS 2015, it is not showing up in my toolbox.. What am I missing and how to I correct? Thanks.

Comment: This article is very interesting too and was a much greater help to me:
[Embedding winforms graph in wpf window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377862/embedding-winforms-graph-in-wpf-window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint is in the namespace name: `Systems.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`, it's a `System.Windows.Forms` component: WinForms. WPF is completely different (though its placement immediately in `System.Windows` (`System.Windows.Controls`) will lead to some confusion.

You can still use it, but you need to use `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost` to host a WinForms component in a WPF XAML document, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms751761(v=vs.100).aspx

Alternatively it's probably best to stick to WPF and use a WPF-based charting control, there is sage advice here: [WPF chart controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577278/wpf-chart-controls)