# How to display audio signal on Universal Window Platfom (UWP) C#?

Tags: c#, audio, uwp

I want to display signal from audio file (ex: .mp3, .wav, .wma,..) to view on Universal Windows App. It may be look like this:
[image]

How to do it, which Control should I use and are there any libraries can help I do it on UWP? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options out there readily available. Here's just 2 of them:

- [clarkezone/audiovisualizer](https://github.com/clarkezone/audiovisualizer) (VU Meters, spectrum & waveform plotting)
- [NAudio.WaveFormRenderer](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio.WaveFormRenderer) (Plots waveforms i.e. PCM data); Maybe [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnFoVuOVrUQ) will be useful as well

Otherwise once (a while ago now) I used the old windows forms chart embedded into a WPF application (have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377862/embedding-winforms-graph-in-wpf-window) if its useful).